# How can I create an executable from a scrapy project?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, python-3.8

Lets say you need to distribute a Scrapy 2.1.0 project to someone and they don't know python. 
How do you package this project up into an executable that can be run by double clicking or via command line passing arguments?

*project structure*:

```
proj/
  scrapy_proj_name/
    scrapy_proj_name/
      spiders/
        my_spider.py
    items.py
    middelwares.py
    pipelines.py
    settings.py
  venv/
  .gitignore
  requirements.txt
```

Now I run the crawler using this `scrapy crawl my_spider -a param1=foo -o output.csv` from python shell, but I need to do it as `program.exe foo` or `program.exe foo output.csv` from command line.

Has anyone ever managed to do this?

Comment: Does https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/discussions/topics/22000009240 help?

Comment: I have never used PyInstaller.. so it's quite hard for me to follow. But if the folder structure in the comment was not a one liner it would try.